# Writing a program in Python to check whether a number is a palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

I am new to programming in Python and am writing a program to check whether an integer with at most six digits is a palindrome.  Here is my code:

```
def digits(n):
    a = (n%10)/1
    b = ((n-a)%100)/10
    c = ((n-a-10*b)%1000)/100
    d = ((n-a-10*b-100*c)%10000)/1000
    e = ((n-a-10*b-100*c-1000*d)%100000)/10000
    f = ((n-a-10*b-100*c-1000*d-10000*e)%1000000)/100000
    
n = 123321
digits(n)

def palindrome(n):
    if a==f and b==e and c==d:
        return True
        print("is a palindrome")
    else:
        return False
        print("is not a palindrome")

palindrome(n)
```

The function digits( ) gives me the first six digits of the number I put in.  The palindrome function checks whether the first digit is equal to the sixth, the second to the fifth, and so on.  I get the following error message when I try to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in palindrome
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>
```

It says that the variable 'a' is not defined.  I thought 'a' was defined when I ran the digits( ) function.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: You are assigning variables which are local to the digits function. I suggest you return a list or dictionary from your digits function instead, and you can pass that into the palindrome function

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying I should define a, b, c, d, e, f outside of the functions?

Comment: @DS `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` are defined inside the function `digits()`. So they are not accessible inside `palindrome()` as it does not know about them

Comment: @D_S I see that Maxijazz has posted an answer where `digits` returns a list, although I suggest that you adapt that answer to take into account Thierry Lathuille's comment below it.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is raised because 'a' is defined in the scope of `digits`, and not passed to `palindrome`.

You can return the digits and pass them like [seth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64297324/13122252) offered, but in python using every type's best quality is an art.

In your case, accessing with index is done better with string or list rather than integer, so [raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64297363/13122252)'s answer is better in that way.

But even a better solution can be achieved with utilizing the slicing functionality of string, which leads me to the most pythonic solution I can think of:

`is_palindrom = lambda number: str(number) == str(number)[::-1]`

What it does is looks at the number as a string, looks at it like a string backwards and compares them.

And it works on any number.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` are local variables. Make them global variables like so:

```
def digits(n):
    a = (n%10)/1
    b = ((n-a)%100)/10
    c = ((n-a-10*b)%1000)/100
    d = ((n-a-10*b-100*c)%10000)/1000
    e = ((n-a-10*b-100*c-1000*d)%100000)/10000
    f = ((n-a-10*b-100*c-1000*d-10000*e)%1000000)/100000
    return a, b, c, d, e, f
    
n = 123321
a, b, c, d, e, f = digits(n)

def palindrome(n, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    if a==f and b==e and c==d:
        return True
        print("is a palindrome")
    else:
        return False
        print("is not a palindrome")

palindrome(n, a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Comment: Global variables are usually something to avoid. Here, `a, b, c, d, e, f = digits(n)` should be part of the `palindrome` function, which only needs one parameter, `n`, as the others can be deduced from it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Seth and Alani pointed out, you face the problem that a-f are only available within the function.

There are two other points I want to address:

1. You don't need modulo calculations to get the n'th digit. You can simply cast your number into a string and access the digits by indices.
2. Your prints won't work because they come after return and are therefore not reachable.

---

```
def palindrome(number):
    number_str = str(number)
    if number_str[0] == number_str[5] and number_str[1] == number_str[4] and number_str[2] == number_str[3]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


n = 123321
if palindrome(n):
    print(f"{n} is a palindrome")
else:
    print(f"{n} is not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `a` isn't defined is that you're just typing it as a variable, when `a` is only defined inside of the function `digits`. Furthermore, the function `digits` does not return anything. Because of that, even if you were to call that function to get the `a` variable that is hidden inside it, the function would return `null`.

So, to solve these problems, you will have to replace the `a` in your `palindrome` function with `digits(n)[a]`, and you will have to make you `digits` function return something, preferably a simple list of `a` through `f`.

Here I put in my corrections and some other minor things, with comments to show why I did everything.

```
def digits(n):
    a = (n % 10) / 1
    b = ((n - a) % 100) / 10
    c = ((n - a - 10 * b) % 1000) / 100
    d = ((n - a - 10 * b - 100 * c) % 10000) / 1000
    e = ((n - a - 10 * b - 100 * c - 1000 * d) % 100000) / 10000
    f = ((n - a - 10 * b - 100 * c - 1000 * d - 10000 * e) % 1000000) / 100000

    # returns a list of all the variables you created, so you can access them from outside.
    return [a, b, c, d, e, f]


# if you call this variable "n" then it can get confusing because all the functions also use "n". the functions will 
# therefore "shadow 'n' from outer scope", which is something we want to avoid.
number = 123321


def palindrome(n):
    # here we are calling the digits function on "n", and collecting the values from that list we made.
    if digits(n)[0] == digits(n)[5] and digits(n)[1] == digits(n)[4] and digits(n)[2] == digits(n)[3]:
        # you can't return True before you print, because when you return something the function instantly quits, and 
        # the print() statement will never be reached.
        print("is a palindrome")
        return True
    else:
        print("is not a palindrome")
        return False


palindrome(number)
```

Comment: You should call `digits(n)` only once and store the output in a variable.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille ah I see what you mean, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number into a string and check if the reverse of the string matches with original string. That will be the easiest way to do it. I understand that you may have to check them using numbers.

Below, I have provided you solutions for both numeric value processing and string processing. Also, this solution does not limit you to six digits.

**Numeric processing:**

```
def check_numeric_pal(numval):
    temp = numval
    ln = len(str(temp))
    x = int(ln/2)
    for i in range (x):
        ln -= 1
        a = int(temp/(10**ln))
        b = int(temp%10)
        if a != b:
            print (numval, 'is NOT a Palindrome')
            break
        temp = int((temp - (a* (10**ln) + b))/10)
        ln -= 1
    else:
        print (numval, 'is a Palindrome')
```

**string processing**

```
def check_palindrome(numval):
    if str(numval) == str(numval)[::-1]:
        print (numval,'is a Palindrome')
    else:
        print (numval,'is NOT a Palindrome')
```

**Calling the numeric function:**

```
print ('Processing as numerics values')   
check_numeric_pal(12345654321)
check_numeric_pal(12345678901)
check_numeric_pal(123321)
check_numeric_pal(123456)
check_numeric_pal(12321)
check_numeric_pal(12345)
```

**Calling the string function**

```
print ()   
print ('Processing as a string')   
check_palindrome(12345654321)
check_palindrome(12345678901)
check_palindrome(123321)
check_palindrome(123456)
check_palindrome(12321)
check_palindrome(12345)
```

**The output for these are:**

```
Processing as numerics values
12345654321 is a Palindrome
12345678901 is NOT a Palindrome
123321 is a Palindrome
123456 is NOT a Palindrome
12321 is a Palindrome
12345 is NOT a Palindrome

Processing as a string
12345654321 is a Palindrome
12345678901 is NOT a Palindrome
123321 is a Palindrome
123456 is NOT a Palindrome
12321 is a Palindrome
12345 is NOT a Palindrome
```

However, if you want to test it using the number pattern, yes, you need to divide and check.

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange 'palindrome' function as put 'digits' function's operations inside it. Also, I suggest you to initialize a,b,c,d,e,f as int variables.

Answer (score -1):

Another way without using string conversion is as below:

```
    def palendrome(a): 
        l=[]
        while True:
            l.append(a%10)
            a=a//10
            if a<1 : break 
        return (True if l==l[::-1] else False)
```

Comment: The question was about a _specific_ error in the code, about variables not being defined. It wasn't just aking for any palindrome checker code.